# Unset elements using array keys

Tags: php, arrays, unset

So I need to delete some array elements, is there easy way not including foreach loop?

```
$privateData = ['id', 'date', 'whatever'];

foreach($privateData as $privateField) {
    unset($request[$privateField]);
}
```

I tried to search array_map array_walk functions for examples but I did not find any.

Comment: is request your array?

Comment: In fact, any such "way" will be internally a loop. So why worry?

Comment: I think that I read somewhere, that array_* functions are slightly faster than for example foreach

Comment: or maybe not http://willem.stuursma.name/2010/11/22/a-detailed-look-into-array_map-and-foreach/ :-D but this is an old article for PHP 5.3..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = array_diff_key($request, array_flip(['id', 'date', 'whatever']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it using `array_map`:

```
array_map(function($privateField) use ($request) {
    unset($request[$privateField]);
}, $privateData);
```

You need to use the `use` option to access `$request` from the outer scope.

I don't know why you'd want to do it this way. The `foreach` loop is much clearer. But since you asked.

Comment: A loop by any other name... ;)